# VIM : PluginList or BundleList doesnt show the list of plugins. What to do?

Tags: windows, vim

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle/autoload
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

" The following are examples of different formats supported.
" Keep Plugin commands between vundle#begin/end.
" plugin on GitHub repo
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
" plugin from http://vim-scripts.org/vim/scripts.html
Plugin 'L9'
" Git plugin not hosted on GitHub
Plugin 'git://git.wincent.com/command-t.git'
" git repos on your local machine (i.e. when working on your own plugin)
Plugin 'file:///home/gmarik/path/to/plugin'
" The sparkup vim script is in a subdirectory of this repo called vim.
" Pass the path to set the runtimepath properly.
Plugin 'rstacruz/sparkup', {'rtp': 'vim/'}
" Install L9 and avoid a Naming conflict if you've already installed a
" different version somewhere else.
Plugin 'ascenator/L9', {'name': 'newL9'}

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
"  Powerline setup
set guifont=DejaVu\ Sans\ Mono\ for\ Powerline\ 9
set laststatus=2

call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
" To ignore plugin indent changes, instead use:
"filetype plugin on
"
" Brief help
" :PluginList       - lists configured plugins
" :PluginInstall    - installs plugins; append `!` to update or just :PluginUpdate
" :PluginSearch foo - searches for foo; append `!` to refresh local cache
" :PluginClean      - confirms removal of unused plugins; append `!` to auto-approve removal
"
" see :h vundle for more details or wiki for FAQ
" Put your non-Plugin stuff after this line

set textwidth=79  " lines longer than 79 columns will be broken
set shiftwidth=4  " operation >> indents 4 columns; << unindents 4 columns
set tabstop=4     " a hard TAB displays as 4 columns
set expandtab     " insert spaces when hitting TABs
set softtabstop=4 " insert/delete 4 spaces when hitting a TAB/BACKSPACE
set shiftround    " round indent to multiple of 'shiftwidth'
set autoindent    " align the new line indent with the previous line
```

This is my `_vimrc` file data on WinVim but when i enter `:PluginList`, 
it shows `Not an editor command: PluginList`
How could I see all my loaded plugins? 
At first I was able to see it, but after a restart, it's not working. 
I've just started using vim for python dev. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can give `:scriptnames` and see the plugins. The command you specified is a user defined one and it needs the function in vimrc or any other plugin files

Comment: thanks @SibiCoder for partially solving my problem but what can I do to install plugins from the vim itself, it used to work with :PluginInstall but doesnt work now.

Comment: "What to do?" Ask on your plugin manager's issue tracker, obviously.

Comment: I used to work with remote desktops with access to the clients websites alone and hence used to copy plugins content and save plugin files manually. If thats not the case for you, To install in vim, you can simply download the plugins and put them in ~/.vim/plugin/ directory. No need of installing anything. You may need to reinstall(download and put in .vim directory) A frsh install will help. You can post the output of :version here, for improved help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vundle only expects `Plugin` entries between `call vundle#begin()` and `call vundle#end()`. If you remove the following lines everything should work as you expect:

```
"  Powerline setup
set guifont=DejaVu\ Sans\ Mono\ for\ Powerline\ 9
set laststatus=2
```